# What tools can create a map of my network?

Tags: networking

> This is a [Canonical Question](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986) about network mapping software.

Are there any good network mapping tools for creating a visual representation of the network?

I'm talking about an automatic mapping tool that will do a scan of the network and make a map for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Dude](http://www.mikrotik.com/thedude.php) does a good job.

Comment: I came into work this morning and found my boss using it :), it does a good job but looking at it makes me think how hard it would be to make a really good one.

Comment: A network management app that only runs on Windows is like a car that only runs on quicksand.

Answer (score 1):

To create a textual representation of the network, use [nmap](http://nmap.org/), if you want a GUI use [Zenmap GUI](http://nmap.org/zenmap/)

As far as creating a *visual* representation of the output, you're going to need to do that manually (e.g. [dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/), [Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/visio), [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/OmniGraffle/)).

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the [Weathermap](http://www.network-weathermap.com/) project.  This generally works best in conjunction with some of the larger RRD based monitoring tools which provide auto-discovery and performance monitoring.

- [Cacti](http://cacti.net)
- [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com)
- [Zenoss](http://zenoss.com)

Answer (score 1):

There is an app I use called "kiss the net" that scans and generates a pdf network map for you.

It's actually based on a server monitoring/management product called "The Dude" made by mikrotik.

http://www.mikrotik.com/download/KTN_1.0beta1.zip
Requirements: Windows XP/2000/2003/Vista with Internet Explorer 6 or better.

Note: the dude is the full version of the software that someone else has listed here. This one simply generates a network map along with a table of machines it discovers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're looking for an automated solution, but [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/OmniGraffle/) is a great Mac application  for making flowcharts and the like. It comes with a "stencil" for electronics that you might find on a network.

**EDIT:** Well, you now changed your post to say that you'd like an automated solution, but I'll leave my post here. If you find a program that can scan a network and export GraphViz files, then you can use OmniGraffle to make pretty graphs.

Answer (score 0):

HP's [Network Node Manager](https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-15-119_4000_100__) performs automatic discovery of your network, and can provide a graphical output of what it has discovered, along with links between devices. I don't know if it supports exporting that data to an editable image format; in any case, most people I've talked to have always preferred manually created diagrams as they tend to be clearer and better laid out.

Answer (score 0):

I've never played with it much but I've heard good things about [netdisco](http://netdisco.org/):

> Designed for moderate to large
>   networks, configuration information
>   and connection data for network
>   devices are retrieved by SNMP. With
>   Netdisco you can locate the switch
>   port of an end-user system by IP or
>   MAC address. Data is stored using a
>   SQL database for scalability and
>   speed. Layer-2 topology protocols such
>   as CDP (Cisco Discovery Protocol)
>   optionally provides automatic
>   discovery of the network topology.
>
> The network is inventoried by both
>   device model and operating system
>   (like IOS). Netdisco uses router ARP
>   tables and L2 switch MAC forwarding
>   tables to locate nodes on physical
>   ports and track them by their IP
>   addresses. For each node, a time
>   stamped history of the ports it has
>   visited and the IP addresses it has
>   used is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Tideway Foundation is a tool for automated network discovery and application modeling that can draw visual representations of your network. You can [download a free virtual appliance](http://www.tideway.com/downloads/) from their website.

**Note**: I used to work for Tideway and still have an interest in the company.